# How to get Session ID for PPPOE session?

Tags: linux, pppoe

I am using rp-pppoe 3.10. I have configured a PPPoE server and client. How do I find out the PPPoE session ID assigned by the server to client when the session is established? Is it updated in any file in /etc/ppp folder or some where else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pppoe` logs this through syslog:

```
pppoe[2195]: PPP session is 2166 (0x876)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..In my case, I initiate at a time 26 pppoe sessions. If pppoe session ID is logged in the "/var/log/messages", how can I find the session ID related to specific pppoe session?

Comment: @Ravi: The value in the square brackets next to `pppoe` is the process ID of the pppoe process, which should allow you to identify a particular instance in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

cat /proc/net/pppoe will give you the session ID, server MAC address and the physical interface device which the PPPoE session is created on.